# FFMPEG How to apply subtitles [ass] on a live video stream

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming, subtitle

I am going to develop a camera recording application.

One of the feature is to apply subtitles while recording. Users can key in subtitles on the camera preview screen when the camera is recording.

I know I can apply the subtitles after the record is finished by running:

```
ffmpeg -i ./file.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -vf "ass=t.ass" out.mp4
```

but which takes a very long time. So it will be better to do it on the fly (while recording a video).

Notice: the subtitle itself is also a live-stream.

Any one help?

Comment: Since this question is now 3 years old with no answer: Were you successful in the end? Because I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: no. I eventually ended with overlaying text on video frames directly by manipulating pixels.

Comment: I am searching for some solution for several hours but I cannot find any good solution, The drawtext filter is working but its not much flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I am also searching the same thing but looks like I need to dig in to the ffmpeg.c file in order to find out the function responsible to embed the subtitle track in the MP4 file. I have written a C library which muxes H.264 and ACC live streams to create an MP4 file (i.e. recording).

Comment: Now I am just trying to add the subtitle as the third stream to create a mkv file. This method is really fast almost immediate as ffmpeg just appends the text file(subtitle) at the end of the video file.